# Campo AutoCompleteFor requerido

Tags: javascript, html, .net

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdPuertoOrigen, "Puerto de Origen")
@Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.IdPuertoOrigen, model => model.PuertoOrigen_Descripcion, false, Url.Action("AutocompletePuertoSearch", "Puerto", new { area = "Maestros" }), "width: 80%;")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPuertoOrigen)
```

El autocompletefor necesito que sea obligatorio de llenar, pero no se cómo hacerlo, me recomendaron con javascript pero no encuentro la forma, si me pueden ayudar les agradeceria mucho.

Comment: estas usando asp.net ?

Comment: @Tegito123 Si estoy usando asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias establecer **atributos** html: 
ejemplo

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required="required" } })
```

usa el required 
espero te ayude !!